# Light for Tubus rear rack

Tags: rack, taillight

I recently received a Tubus rack that I am happy with.
In the instructions there is a wide rear light with a double point attachment.
I want one of those big lights - can someone tell me of one?

[see light in this](http://www.tubus.com/documents/1321360149_Carry.pdf)

Comment: What country do you live in?

Comment: It is in my profile - US.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the one in the diagram you linked:
[http://www.amazon.com/D-Toplight-Rear-Light-Design-backlight/dp/B000NW65U4/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NW65U4)

That one requires external power from a dynamo hub, though I have seen references online to a battery-powered version of the same light.  The same company, Busch & Müller, makes a few others with the same mounting system.  In general you can find these things by searching for "European" style taillights, as they are popular in that region (but not in the US).  Here's one that works on batteries: [http://www.amazon.com/4D-Toplight-Permanent-Tail-Light/dp/B0051WTS0A/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051WTS0A) (the Senso model is similar but adds an auto on/off capability based on ambient light level).

Here's another that fits the same mounting holes but with a very different design (for use with a dynamo hub only): http://supernova-lights.com/en/products/e3_tail_light2.html

Finally, some taillights have available mounting plates for 50mm rack mounts, such as this: http://ecom1.planetbike.com/3108.html or this: [http://www.amazon.com/Cat-Eye-Tailight-Rack-Mount/dp/B002P793U4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002P793U4)

Comment: Thanks.  I will order and test a light before formally accepting an answer.

Comment: @Blam - Both linked lights require a dynamo to power the light. The Busch & Müller 4DToplight Senso Multi can be powered by batteries or a dynamo source.  See http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/taillights.asp

Comment: @Rider_X: thanks for clarifying that.  I added a battery-powered version of the B&M light as well, since US cyclists usually don't have dynamos.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - It is a shame dynamos haven't taken of in North America. Won't commute without one!

Comment: I second the recommendation for the B&M Toplight Linetec. Uses a single AA battery and seems to last for ages. The design is meant to give larger lit area so judging the distance to you is easier for other roads users.

Comment: And I found this http://ecom1.planetbike.com/3018_1.html.

Comment: The current standard for mounting a light on a rear rack is a horizontal bracket with two holes either 50mm or 80mm apart. Most of what's currently available is made by Busch & Müller, but any light that uses two posts that distance apart would likely work.

Also, the Planet Bike small part "Taillight Rack Bracket" will adapt most of their taillights (including their very bright "Superflash" line) for use on a rear rack of this specification, since it has two holes oriented horizontally, 50mm apart. http://ecom1.planetbike.com/3108.html